# Anguler2 js: getting no compatible version found : @types/node@^5.8.0

Tags: angular, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to install npm packages using npm install command. My node js version is 5.8.0. While installing, I am getting below error continuously.

Below is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "angular2-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^5.8.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

[image: Error screen shot]

I have copied the package.json file from [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). Please explain the error and suggest me a solution. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my rc version. It's working fine.